# Will enabling Hyper-V on Windows 8 impact GPU performance?

Tags: windows-8, gpu, hyper-v

I am vaguely aware that when you enable the Hyper-V feature on Windows 8 it somehow affects the host operating system itself, is that right?

So if I've got a PC with an nVidia GTX770 and I enable Hyper-V, are my frame-rates in Far Cry 3: Blood Dragon going to go down?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but when installed Hyper-V, I couldn't use my cable tuners because Windows Media Center said my graphics card wasn't HDCP compliant.  Uninstalling fixed the problem.  So it's certainly doing something strange with the graphics drivers.

Comment: @MarkRendle - Where exactly did you read that Hyper-V would affect the host operating system?

Comment: @Ramhound I can't remember, I had it installed before on a not-for-gaming PC and it did something weird.

Comment: @MarkRendle - Define "weird"....

Comment: It virtualized the network adapter in the host OS, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is actually a problem, which is discussed here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/afe0c6cf-fbf4-4e07-8ccc-78de5e481bd3/does-enabling-client-hyperv-reduce-the-hosts-gaming-performance.

I have a VM running on Hyper-V (Windows 8) constantly on my machine, which has a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 570 and haven't noticed (visually, not by FPS measuring) lower than 'the game runs smoothly' FPS but that's probably because the games I've run are not that GPU-hungry.

I guess a benchmark would really tell the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Having Hyper-V installed on my gaming machine seemed to reserve about 25% of my GPU (measured with nvInspector) while gaming.  I went out of my mind trying to figure out why my FPS dropped so sharply before I saw someone advise removing Hyper-V to solve a related issue.

Running on an AMD Phenom II 955BE with AMD-V on, but IOMMU (AMD-Vi) off.  I should try with IOMMU on to see if that has an impact, but I probably won't get around to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure.. Run [3DMark](http://www.3dmark.com/) on your system before and after enabling Hyper-V to see what the difference is :)

Besides... you know you want to benchmark your new rig ;)